# algorithm alternating motion recursion

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, server, recursive-datastructures

How can I devise an algorithm that inputs an array of numbers - of any length - and determines if a function they form represents an alternating motion?

For example, for an array [-3, -2, -4, 4, 2, 5, 0, 3, -10, 4] the output would be yes since the numbers go up-down-up-down-up-down-up-down-up. For an array [3, -2, -4, 4, 5, 7, 10, 3, -10, 4] the output would be no since the numbers sometimes go only down (3, -2, -4) or only up (-4, 4, 5, 7, 10).

I only want the algorithm. I'm not planning to code it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take the difference between two consecutive values: the sign of that difference should flip in each iteration of your loop over the array:

```js
function isUpDown(arr) {
  if (arr.length < 3 || arr[0] === arr[1]) return false;
  for (let i = 2, sign = Math.sign(arr[0] - arr[1]); i < arr.length; i++, sign = -sign) {
    if (sign !== Math.sign(arr[i] - arr[i-1])) return false;
  }
  return true;
}

console.log(isUpDown([-3, -2, -4, 4, 2, 5, 0, 3, -10, 4])); // true
console.log(isUpDown([3, -2, -4, 4, 5, 7, 10, 3, -10, 4])); // false
```